# Which index type should i choose in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-compass

PAYMENT_ID is a non-null column. I will get an average of 10 documents per quey by PAYMENT_ID.

When i create index for that column in mongo db, mongodb compass asks me to choose index type. Here are the selections. Which option would be the best for this kind of acolumn?

[image]

Comment: for what hell this question was voted negative? extra smart coder don't support basics? I  also tried to find the same answer and landed here. Have some dignity dudes.

Answer (score 1):

Asc - Ascending order

Desc - Descending order

This is use in query order - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

2dsphere - Used for [geospatial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/2dsphere/) queries.

Text - Used for [text search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) queries.

For normal indexes you should select asc or desc.

Comment: still not clear the diff between Asc-Desc. how diff logic from conventional db like mysql index. why need 2 diff orders?